Big Query, SQL, Dynamic Key
I need to get the start and end time for each row. The response looks like below. With big query I cant concat keys dynamically. How to do it?

Take the first key value pair in the menus dictionary and the first section and assume that as the store business hours.
Note: daysBitArray starts with Monday and indicates the days of the week for this time window is applicable. The might be more than element in the regularHours array.
Please use json parsing and do not use regex.

example value of response column:
{

"data": {

"menuMapping": [

    {

    "menuType": "MENU_TYPE_FULFILLMENT_DELIVERY",

    "menuUUID": "6ad9adbc-aac0-4796-89da-03ca8dfdd12f"

    }

],

"menus": {

        6ad9adbc-aac0-4796-89da-03ca8dfdd12f :

        {

        "sections" : [

            0 : {

                "regularHours" : [

                0 : {
                    "daysBitArray":[false,false,true,false,false,false,false],
                    "endTime":"21:00”
                    "startTime":"11:00"}

note that each row will have different menuUUID.
cannot use CONCAT or || menuid || since Big query needs it to be constant.
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(menu, '$.sections[0].regularHours[0].startTime') AS store_opening_time,
  JSON_EXTRACT(menu, '$.sections[0].regularHours[0].endTime') AS store_closing_time,
  JSON_EXTRACT(menu, '$.sections[0].regularHours[0].daysBitArray') AS days_bit_array
FROM (
  SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(response, '$.data.menus') AS menus
  FROM
`arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours`
  WHERE
JSON_EXTRACT(response, '$.data') IS NOT NULL
) AS m,
 UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(menus)) AS menu
 LIMIT 1

Trying this but "no data to display"
